# Oracle manipulate pivot xml

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below table:

| MATCH_DATE | LOCATION | HOME_TEAM_NAME | AWAY_TEAM_NAME | HOME_TEAM_POINTS | AWAY_TEAM_POINTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-2018 | Snowley | Underrated United | Terrible Town | 2 | 0 |
| 01-JAN-2018 | Coldgate | Average Athletic | Champions City | 1 | 4 |
| 01-FEB-2018 | Dorwall | Terrible Town | Average Athletic | 0 | 1 |
| 01-MAR-2018 | Coldgate | Average Athletic | Underrated United | 3 | 3 |
| 02-MAR-2018 | Newdell | Champions City | Terrible Town | 8 | 0 |

I'm trying to dynamically pivot it but the output generated is xml. How can I show this xml as a table?

Query:

```
with rws as (
  select location
  from   match_results
)
  select xmlserialize ( -- formats an XML document
           document location_xml as clob indent size=2
         ) location_xml
  from   rws
  pivot xml (
    count (*) matches for location in ( any )
  );
```

Result

```xml
LOCATION_XML
<PivotSet>
  <item>
    <column name="LOCATION">Coldgate</column>
    <column name="MATCHES">2</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name="LOCATION">Dorwall</column>
    <column name="MATCHES">1</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name="LOCATION">Newdell</column>
    <column name="MATCHES">1</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name="LOCATION">Snowley</column>
    <column name="MATCHES">1</column>
  </item>
</PivotSet>
```

Comment: What output are you trying to get - two rows with one column for each location, which breaks the SQL rule of knowing the number of columns before the query; or two columns with one row for each location, which can be extracted from the XML easily but which can be done with simple aggregation rather than a pivot?

Comment: I'm trying to get one row with for 4 columns (for each distinct location) without having to manually list them like in a normal pivot.